# How can parse a text to html in a span?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an span which recieves a variable text:

`<span>{{$scope.text}}</span>`

Since Backend I am recieving this String:

```
"text <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/QrKSV.png"/>"
```

And I am store it in the scope.text.

But part of `<img>` is not recognize as image but as text, I am looking for a way to show the part of img as an image.(It is for implemanting emoticons in a chat)

Comment: El.innerHTML="<h1>yourtext</h1>"

Comment: Add relevant code please.

Comment: you can try `$scope.text = $scope.text.replace('/^text /, '')`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? It sounds like you're trying to simply remove the text and not show any node attributes. There are different methods that return similar results (-ish). NOTE: the innerText attribute is either deprecated or handled differently in different browsers! (http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)

```js
var myEl = document.getElementsByClassName("data-pane")[0];
var TCEl = document.getElementsByClassName("text-content-container")[0];
var IHEl = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-html-container")[0];
var ITEl = document.getElementsByClassName("inner-text-container")[0];

// First, let's output the text content
TCEl.innerHTML = "<h2>Text Content of data pane:</h2><p>"+myEl.textContent;
// console.log("text content of data pane: "+myEl.textContent);

// then, let's output the innerHTML
IHEl.innerHTML = "<h2>InnerHTML Content of data pane:</h2><p>"+myEl.innerHTML;
// console.log("innerHTML content of data pane: "+myEl.innerHTML);


// then, let's output the innerText
ITEl.innerHTML = "<h2>InnerText Content of data pane:</h2><p>"+myEl.innerText;
// console.log("innerText content of data pane: "+myEl.innerText);
```

```html
<div class="data-pane">
  This is a <span class="foobly">span tag, nested,</span> and an
  <img alt="foo of the bar in the BAZ, man!" />Image with text.
</div>
<div class="results-pane">
  <div class="text-content-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-html-container"></div>
  <div class="inner-text-container"></div>
</div>
```